# ADFS Event 329 - Certificate Could Not Be Decrypted

Tags: certificate, windows-event-log, adfs

Using MS scripts, I attempted a migration of an ADFS 2.0 configuration (on Windows 2008R2) to a new ADFS server (Windows 2016) server. I have warnings in my event log that seem to be linked, via the thumbprint in the error, to the token-decrypting and token-signing certificates.

The EventID was: 329. The error was: "The certificate that is identified by thumbprint 'xxxxxx' could not be decrypted using the keys for X.509 certificate private key sharing. MSIS7708: The group for X.509 certificate private key sharing with the distinguished name 'yyyyyy' does not exist."

How do I resolve these warnings?

Comment: Did you export the private keys when you migrated the certificates to the new server? It would help if you provided a link to whatever instructions you followed.

Comment: I exported the service certificate. And, instructions I followed were at https://itsalwaysmyproblem.com/2016/10/02/migrating-from-adfs-2-1-to-4-0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you the person on reddit I noticed following [my instructions](https://itsalwaysmyproblem.com/2016/10/02/migrating-from-adfs-2-1-to-4-0/), who reported that their service account had been changed? If that's you - or if your service account has changed anyway between the old ADFS server and the new one - you may be having permissions issues in AD - the new ADFS service account might not be able to access AD objects created by the old service account.

If that's the case, use `get-AdfsProperties` on your ADFS server and look for CertificateSharingContainer. You should see something like this:

```
CertificateSharingContainer : CN=yourguid-goes-here-6b78-9deadbeef000,CN=ADFS,CN=Microsoft,CN=Program Data,DC=your,DC=domain,DC=name,DC=here
```

Find that container in AD, using ADUC. Verify the correct service account has permissions. If not, add them, bounce the ADFS service and see if that helps.

Comment: Rob, thanks for the help. Yes I did use that blog post to generally migrate the ADFS server we have. I later noted that the items being complained about were the token certificates, not the service one. I regenerated them and the error went away.